# Convert VOXEL model to soft Mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm working with models generated as voxels like those showing in the following picture from the internet:

[image]

I'm trying to do basically the same you see on the image: turn a voxel-based model into a soft-mesh based one. Don't mind abut texture mapping, just geometry.

Is this achievable in Blender?

Comment: The picture you attached looks interesting. Do you happen to still have the source to this picture? :)

Comment: @NicholasTJ
https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/surface_reconstruction/pami/pami.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell you how to import voxel data into Blender, but if there's no dedicated importer, you can try [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) to convert to a supported format. For example, PLY or STL to import as vertices. If there's no real surface yet, you may use MeshLab's pointcloud triangulation capabilities and export as .OBJ.

Once you have a mesh object in Blender with a surface, try the **Laplacian Smooth Modifier**, which lets you smooth mesh surfaces while retaining a lot of detail.  Go to *Properties Editor > Modifiers* and add it to your object.

More information: [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/laplacian_smooth.html)

Comment: Is the link broken for anyone else?  Maybe it's my Ubuntu's fault.  I'm on 16.04

Comment: No, the page is apparently gone. I replaced the link with one to the new Blender documentation for it (non-wiki).

Answer (score 1):

Another program that supports Voxels, assuming they're xyz, is Paraview:

http://paraview.org/

If you import it as a table you can run the following filters:
1. Table to Points
2.  3D Delauny

When you're done, you can export the geometry as an X3D and then import it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a voxel representation, you can use some implementation of [Marching Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) to create a mesh from the voxels. It is possible to import a stack of images as a 'voxel stack' in [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) which uses ImageJ.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be about blender.

Comment: Like @David said, answers should directly relate to Blender. If you know how to do it, with a modifier or script, please add that to your answer.

Comment: It is technically correct, but how do you run Marching Cubes on Blender?

Comment: If I could downvote David's answer, I would.  Who the heck cares whether they can do it in Blender as long as they can accomplish their goals?  What if the viewer can't make the higher-voted answers work for them?  They'll need a second thing to try