# Volumetrics data into mesh

Tags: mesh, volumetrics, conversion

Is there any way to convert volumetrics into mesh? I managed to recreate 3D structure from 177 serial images (confocal microscopy) using volumetrics, using guidelines found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gFUYtuDv_Q)

I'm not satisfied with the effect - the structures are blurry and I'm looking for sharp, defined edges.

[image]

Any unconventional way to convert this volumetric data into actual mesh?

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/convert-voxel-model-to-soft-mesh

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get sharp defined edges using volumetrics - see [Give this mesh a uniform thickness on all the tubes and unions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81396/29586). Assuming your source data is to sufficient resolution then it should just be a matter of adjusting the Volume Sampling settings in the Render properties.

[image: Volume Sampling properties]

Decrease the Step Size to get better resolution. This is defined in blender units so pick a value that is close to the resolution of your data based on the size of the volume. If the number of steps does not span the volume then increase Max Steps to compensate.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to build a mesh

Comment: In that case, I think your best option would be use a python script to use your volumetrics data to place mesh elements such as metaballs at points where the density is above a threshold - and possibly also sized based on the density. The resultant mesh could then be remeshed and/or manipulated to clean it up (depending on how suitable it is to your needs ‘raw’). Without having access to your data and how you’re currently processing it to provide the volumetrics it will be difficult to provide a more detailed solution.

Comment: @marcheenek a similar question was answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/convert-voxel-model-to-soft-mesh)